# Transaction time - is it Yodlee's time?

Tags: yodlee

On [this page](https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions), you explain that "most sites do not provide the time stamp for a transaction". Yet, on the example output of [getUserTransactions](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactions) you do show field named **postDate** and **transactionDate**. What is the meaning of those fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**transactionDate**- This will return the date on which the transaction happened.

**postDate**- This will return the date on which the transaction was posted/reflected on the banking website.
For e.g., generally credit card transactions get posted on online banking site after 2-3 days of actual transaction execution.

Note:- This depends on the availability of these details on the bank websites.

On the other hand when Yodlee says -"most sites do not provide the time stamp for a transaction" this means sites do not provide actual timestamp(date + time) when any transaction got executed, while they provide the date.